# wrong output from assembly language simulation

Tags: arrays, assembly

To get the output below I am running the following code:

I manually add 4 hex numbers into the array when running the program. These numbers are: 07, FC, 24, and EF. When I run the program with these numbers in the array, the output should be the sum of all these numbers which is 216. I am wondering why I do not see this output.

```
#include <p18F452.inc>

ARRAY   EQU 0x20
SUM     EQU 0x10
COUNT   EQU 0x11
    ORG 0x00
    GOTO START
    ORG 0x30
START:  LFSR FSR1,ARRAY
    MOVLW 4
    MOVWF COUNT
    CLRF WREG
LOOP:   ADDWF POSTINC1,W
    DECF COUNT,F
    BNZ LOOP
    MOVWF SUM
    SLEEP
    END
```

[image: output]

Comment: 0x216 doesn't fit in one byte.

Comment: So where would the rest go?

Comment: You add the overflow to another byte, by the way if you say you're getting incorrect output and ask what's wrong it's usually not a bad idea to add the output.

Comment: that simulator picture shows the output